# Vue.js props, components & data namespace

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I have a Vue.js component it could look like:

```
import Icon from './Components/Icon.vue'
export default {
    props: {
        data: {type: Object}
    },
    data() {
        return {
            label: this.data.label || '',
            icon: this.data.icon || '',
            placeholder: this.data.placeholder || '',
            value: this.data.value || '',
            disabled: this.data.disabled || false,
            readOnly: this.data.readOnly || false,
            options: this.data.options || []
        }
    },
    components: {
        Icon: Icon
    }
}
```

How does the namespace work in Vue? Is both props keys, data return object keys, and all components object keys will be added to the `this` instance? Is there not a risk for bugs/over-writing stuff?

So if I override `this.data` can I still read the original value I received in the `props`?

What is the community practise for setting "default" values in the `data` state object comming from `props` so we can both have a dynamic `state` object, and keep the `props` there in case we need it?

And related: if pass `props` with `v-bind` should I add them to `watch` internally on my component? or make all my dynamic values a computed version taking into consideration `props` everytime it is called?

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: >>And related: if pass props with v-bind should I add them to watch internally on my component? or make all my dynamic values a computed version taking into consideration props everytime it is called?>> The second one. Props are reactive: when incoming prop updates, the component' properites will be updated as well.

Answer (score 12):

Vue will warn you if you have a conflicting property name. For example, if you had this in your component:

```
props: ['foo'],
data() {
  return {
    foo: 'bar',
  }
},
```

You would get this warning:

> [Vue warn]: The data property "foo" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.

And (as the warning alludes to), if you want to set a default value of a prop, you should do it in the definition of the prop like so:

```
props: {
    foo: { type: String, default: 'bar' }
},
```

---

In your example, you are passing a prop named `data` and using it to set the data properties of the Vue component. So the component will have access to `this.label`, `this.icon`, etc., and it will also have access to `this.data.label`, `this.data.icon`, etc.

This isn't overwriting anything because your prop named `data` is referencing a different object than your component's data properties. Bu, you probably don't ever want to name a property `data`, because you can see how it might get confusing.

---

It looks like you are, in general, trying to pass an object with property values to a component instead of having to set each one individually. You can do this with `v-bind` like so:

```
// assuming that var settings = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
<child-component v-bind="settings"></child-component>
```

Child component:

```
props: {
  foo: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  bar: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  // you can still set defaults for props not passed in the object
  baz: { type: Number, default: 0 }, 
}
```